# Async request in react-redux using async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux

I'm new to React and I'm trying to make an Api call to a server then using this this data in my component.

I'm trying to use async await to handle asynchronous

```
const onNotifReceived = async (res) => {
    var updatedQueue = res.updatedQueue;
    updatedQueue["queueNewState"] = await getContactDetails(authClient, res.updatedQueue.queueNewState);
    console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updatedQueue)))
    notifyQueue(updatedQueue); // redux dispatcher
}
```

I notice that `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(updatedQueue)))` is run before other `console.logs`inside the function `getContactDetails`.

But as I know `await` should wait for the response before passing to the next line which is not the case and the problem that I'm not getting `updatedQueue["queueNewState"]` new state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maybe** `getContactDetails()` do not return a promise, but there are delayed operations in.

```
async function xd() {
    await xdd();
    console.log("after xdd");
}
function xdd() {
    setTimeout(() => {
        console.log("1000 later");
    }, 1000);
}
xd();
// after xdd
// (after 1 second)
// 1000 later
```

```
async function xd() {
    await xdd();
    console.log("after xdd");
}
function xdd() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            console.log("1000 later");
            resolve();
        }, 1000);
    });
}
xd();
// (after 1 second)
// 1000 later
// after xdd
```

For first situation, `xdd` runs before `console.log("after xdd");`, but `console.log("1000 later");` will comes out 1 second later.

Comment: Also, objects with function `then` are treated the same as promises.